# Asp.Net The difference of HttpContext.Current.Items and CallContext

Tags: asp.net

I know “ HttpContext.Current.Item” data is live for single HTTP request/Response.
Is also CallContext?

Answer (score 0):

No CallContext is used for .NET Remoting (which I have no experience in).  While it may use similar permission objects, it is used in a completely different paradigm.

From [MSDN](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.runtime.remoting.messaging(v=vs.110).aspx) so you understand, this was a blurb about the messaging namespace that it is in:

> The System.Runtime.Remoting.Messaging namespace contains classes used
>   to create and transmit messages. The remoting infrastructure uses
>   messages to communicate with remote objects. Messages are used to
>   transmit remote method calls, to activate remote objects, and to
>   communicate information. A message object carries a set of named
>   properties, including action identifiers, envoy information, and
>   parameters.